# Is there a way to find out the search keywords in YouTube with Google's Keyword Planner?

Tags: google-search, keywords, google-keyword-tool

Google's Keyword Planner tool enable you to find out the popularity for any  key words searched in Google.
I want to know if Google's Keyword Planner tool or any other tool enable to find out the popularity for key words in YouTube search engine.

Comment: Can you provide a little more information as to specifically what you're looking for, perhaps with an example?

Answer (score 1):

[YouTube has a keyword suggestion tool](https://www.youtube.com/keyword_tool) that appears to be exactly what you are looking for.

You can also use search suggestions from the search box [per this article](https://www.wordstream.com/articles/keyword-research-for-social-media-guide#Keyword-Research-for-YouTube).

[image: YouTube search suggestions]
<sub>(source: [wordstream.com](https://www.wordstream.com/images/screenshots/youtube-suggest-keyword-research-1.gif))</sub>

Comment: YT tells you on this page, that you will have to go to [Adwords](https://adwords.google.com/da/DisplayPlanner/Home) to find this data because they will shut down the YouTube keyword tool on 1st september. But I can not find anything like this tool at Adwords for YouTube. Do you know where to find search volume of YouTube at Adwords? Maybe it would be a good time to update this answer as well :)